# Insert a TeX code into a math mode at LyX

Tags: lyx

If i'm at math mode at LyX and I want to add a TeX code, how can I do it?

This is possible?

i.e something like: `\Ding{152}` (or code that is more then a symbol) in math mode.

Answer (score 4):

In math mode just type the TeX code. Of course, you need to include used packages in the LaTeX Preamble. For example, in math mode

- `\rightarrow` + <kbd>space</kbd> will produce [image: rightarrow];
- if you put `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` into the LaTeX Preamble then you can type `a\leftrightarrowtriangle b`. This results in [image: lrarrowtriangle] or if "Tools > Preferences > Look&Feel > Instant Preview" is turned on then you will see [image: lrarrowtriangle preview] *after leaving* math mode;
- furthermore, you can type `\def\a{\rightarrow}` and use `\a` later on. (Be aware that copying and pasting the `\def`-code will transform it into a `\global\long\def`. This is the same as using "Insert > Math > Macro".)

Overall, you can type probably every TeX code that can be used in math mode. You might find "View > View Source" helpful to check whether LyX understood correctly what you typed. (If you interrupt typing of `\ding{123}` it might come out as `\ding\{123\}`.)